# Executing python script from php

Tags: php, python

I have the following php code which is calling a python script nmapdb.py located in the same folder as the php file.

```
function banner($name) {

$output = exec('python nmapdb.py $name');
echo $output;

}
```

the python scipt is as follows:

```
ip=sys.argv[1]
print("Please get cup of coffee...Coz I am gonna take some time...")
nm=nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan(hosts=ip , arguments='-sV --script=banner')
result=nm.get_nmap_last_output()
fo=open("result.xml","w")
fo.write(result)
fo.close()

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb');


tree=etree.parse('result.xml')
root=tree.getroot()
root.tag
entries=tree.findall('host')
i=0
while i < len(entries):
    sub=entries[i].find('address')
    adr=sub.attrib['addr']
    adrtype=sub.attrib['addrtype']
    sub=entries[i].find('ports')
    sub1=sub.findall('port')
    j=0
    while j < len(sub1):
        prot=sub1[j].attrib['protocol']
        prtid=sub1[j].attrib['portid']
        sub2=sub1[j].find('state')
        stat=sub2.attrib['state']
        sub2=sub1[j].find('service')
        servname=sub2.attrib['name']
        try:
           sub2.attrib['product']
        except KeyError:
           prod='unknown'
        else:
           prod=sub2.attrib['product']
        try:
           sub2.attrib['devicetype']
        except KeyError:
           devtype='unknown'
        else:
           devtype=sub2.attrib['devicetype']
        try:
           sub2.attrib['ostype']
        except KeyError:
           os='unknown'
        else:
           os=sub2.attrib['ostype']
        j=j+1
        comm= "http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip="+adr+"&position=true"
        response = urllib.urlopen(comm).read()
        data=json.loads(response)
        country=data['country_name']
        city=data['city']


        with con:

                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("""INSERT INTO nmap_table (Ip_Addr, Addr_Type, Protocol, Port_Id, State, Service_Name, Product, Device, OS, Country, City) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (adr, adrtype, prot, prtid, stat, servname, prod, devtype, os, country, city))
        i=i+1
print("Kudos....I'm done....Please check the database...")
```

But the problem is that when i am calling the python script from php, it is not working properly...only the first print statement is coming in the browser....whereas the script is working all fine when executed from terminal...PLEASE HELP....

Comment: [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) "The last line from the result of the command" use second argument for output capture

Answer (score 0):

function banner($name) {

$output = exec('python nmapdb.py $name', $full_output);
echo $output;  // Here just last line of script
print_r($full_output); // Here will be all console output of python script
}

Comment: i have tried your solution but still it is not coming properly.... the output in the browser is coming as "Array"....thanks...

Comment: `echo implode('',$full_output)`